# SHA256withRSA with QT

Tags: c++, qt, encryption, google-oauth

For using the google service account I need to create a signature with SHA256withRSA. But I don't find how I can encrypt it with QT.

I already created the header and claim set with the base64 encoding and know how to encrypt with SHA256 but that isn't enough for google.

Can somebody point me in the good direction to encrypt the signature using SHA256withRSA with QT?

Comment: Qt does not provide cryptography functionality. There is QCryptographicHash, which can calculate some ordinary hashes, but that probably does not help you much. You can try using OpenSsl, which is distributed with Qt on Linux and Windows and provides standalone cryptography functions (not very user friendly though). Or try third party libraries, such as [QCA](https://github.com/KDE/qca) or [crypto++](https://www.cryptopp.com/) (I have not used these myself).

Comment: I was hoping that it could be done the easy way with QT. I will try the libraries.